# What is the best way to use number format in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I need to set the "Total Price" value to be a two decimal point value like "56.35". Now it's showing fraction values like "56.3566666". I need it to be formatted by MySQL "SELECT" query.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
select
    format(field, 2) as formatted
from
    table
```

Do note that Format() returns a *string*, and the result will be with two decimal places (in the above example) - i.e. 100 will be formatted as 100.00.

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format).

Answer (score 7):

That works too, but if you need it for further calculations or what not AND you have MySQL > 5.0.8 you could also try:

```
select
    cast(field as decimal(14, 2)) as formatted
from
    table
```

It is a bit more flexible this way! I like flexible...

Answer (score 4):

Hi I thought I wanted FORMAT but didn't like the formatting of the whole number part (with commas)

SELECT ROUND(11000.299, 2);

SELECT ROUND(11000.301, 2);

SELECT ROUND(11000.3, 2);

all three renders 11000.30

```
SELECT FORMAT(11000.3, 2);
```

renders 11,000.3